# Python Flask: Error "The method is not allowed for the requested URL"

Tags: python, flask

I am very new to working with Python Flask and i wanted to try a simple API-example:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        some_json = request.get_json()
        return {'you sent': some_json}, 201

class Multi(Resource):
    def get(self,num):
        return {'result': num*10}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')
api.add_resource(Multi,'/multi/<int:num>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and if I type in the terminal

`-H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"xyz","address":"myaddress"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

I get the following message:

```
{
    "message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this...

Answer (score 1):

Since your are calling the POST HTTP method. You should rename 'get' function in class HelloWorld to 'post'. 'HelloWorld' class can also have both 'get' and a 'post' functions if '/' endpoint should serves both.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def post(self):
        some_json = request.get_json()
        return {'you sent': some_json}, 201

class Multi(Resource):
    def get(self,num):
        return {'result': num*10}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')
api.add_resource(Multi,'/multi/<int:num>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: but then I get the message:  "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"